# Creating a Material-UI tab with image tabs instead of text labels

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use the Material-ui tab component for a vertical tab.  The problem I am having is how to use an image other than the pre-defined icons rather than a text label?

I tried using an Avatar component, breaking Tab like this:

```
    <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)}>
      <Avatar alt="test avatar" src="/logo192.png" />
    </Tab>
```

The Avatar works when I put it in the TabPanel so I know it is right and points to the image correctly, but when I put it in the Tab, as shown above, I get no image, just the "Item Two" label.  Is it possible to create a tab with an image using the ButtonBase?  I couldn't find any sample of using the ButtonBase.  Or do I need to submit a feature request and look elsewhere for now?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You wan't to display an image above the label, like an icon? Or you want the image to be the background of the tab?

Comment: I just want to add to the answers below; both Giovanni's and 3limin4t0r's solution work using a standard HTML image instead of the Material-UI Avatar component if you need more direct control over the image.  My original question referenced the Avatar because it was part of Material-UI but the image actually works better for me because I could make it larger for tired, old, eyes.  Both are great solutions to images in the Material-UI tab component.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you are asking, but you can pass your own images through the `Tab` [`icon`](https://mui.com/components/tabs/#icon-tabs) property to use them as an icon. They don't have to be Material-UI icons.

```
<Tab icon={<Avatar alt="test avatar" src="/logo192.png" />} />
```

```js
const {Tabs, Tab, Avatar} = MaterialUI;

function Demo() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
      <Tabs
        orientation="vertical"
        value={selected}
        onChange={(_, selected) => setSelected(selected)}
      >
        <Tab icon={<Avatar />} />
        <Tab label="second" />
      </Tabs>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@4/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, as well. Thank you, 3limin4t0r.  Another outside-the-documentation-box solution that can be put in my toolbelt for this problem and potentially other places as well.

Answer (score 3):

Ciao, you have this problem because `Tab` does not support `children`. [Material UI docs](https://material-ui.com/api/tab/) says:

> This prop (children) isn't supported. Use the component prop if you need to
> change the children structure.

So you have to use `component` props, for example in this way:

```
<Tab
   label="Item One"
   {...a11yProps(0)}
   value={value}
   component={() => (
      <Button onClick={() => setValue(0)}> // this button to select the Tab (the first one in this case) when you click the Avatar 
         <Avatar src="<an image>" />   // Avatar here
      </Button>
   )}
/>
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-tabs-hooks-forked-pd7k7?file=/src/index.js) a codesandbox example.

Comment: Thank you, Giovanni.  Not only does this solve my problem and give me the images I want for my tabs, it shows how to get outside the documented box and be more creative in other components.  Using component= may not work in every case but having this in my toolbelt will help.

Comment: No problem @Dale. Glad to added something to your toolbelt :)